# How to edit/view a dynamic object in Asp.Net MVC 2 or 3?

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, dynamic-data

I want to used objects that are entirely made of xml, and i want to make a view framework the would allow me to edit / view this object in a asp.net mvc view.

Do you have an idea on how could I accomplish this?

Any idea is good.

Thank you

Edit 1: Example of xml, but this is basic, i want to represent any kind of data in this xml, including base64 pictures

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<product xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">  
     <name xsi:nil="true"></name>
     <description>bqddd</description>
</product>
```

Edit 2: I want to store as xml properties for objects, each object with different properties. And when I edit an object i want to be able to show a different type of interface dinamically for each type of object i have as xml.

Edit 3: I want also to be able to change the view on the fly without the need to recompile, if posible.

Comment: Add an example of your XML's objects...

Comment: Not entirely sure I understand, you **want** to use the dynamic type? Is your xml definition dynamic, such that it changes and you automatically want your objects to pick up their property definitions and values from xml ?

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033444/asp-net-mvc-add-model-meta-data-without-attributes/7035376

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So off the bat I just wrote some code unsure of what you want.

Based on your xml you could just add a ViewModel like:

```
class Product
{
 public string Name..
 public string Description..
}
```

But then you said something about being dynamic and there is something interesting you can do with the [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) class.

Check this code:

```
void Main()
{
    XmlDynamicModel x = new XmlDynamicModel(@"path/myobject.xml");
    //you're element should be <description>value</description>
    //I would rather capitalize the first letter **Description
    Console.WriteLine(x.TheObject.description);
    Console.WriteLine(x.TheObject.name);
}
public class XmlDynamicModel
{
    public XmlDynamicModel(string xmlfile)
    {
      this.TheObject = new ExpandoObject();
      var t = this.TheObject as IDictionary<String, object>;
      XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(xmlfile);
      //get all objects UNDER product
      foreach(var elem in xmlDoc.Descendants().Descendants())
      {
        t[elem.Name.ToString()] = elem.Value.ToString();
      }
    }
    public dynamic TheObject {get;set;}
}
```

You could make it fancier by adding the object name (in this case product) as a property and looking out for different types and setting null values etc.

Hope it helps

Comment: I will check this code tomorrow and I will let you know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since your product could have several inner tags of different types, you should have a ViewModel with properties of metadata... and then a collection of inner properties (that match the inner tags of your XML).

That way, you can loop through the tag collection to display or create a form to edition.

Comment: Could you please provide a link to such kind of example?